# How IIS handle http request headers with same name

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

If I send http request with two same header name, for example:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept: application/xml
```

Which one will be used by IIS?

I have two windows server 2008 R2, and the IIS version is 7.5. But they have different behavior. One accept "application/json", and the other accept "application/xml“. So I want to know if there is configuration in IIS?